# Using a Function to Reformat Zip Codes

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using the below function to try to reformat all values in the 'ZIP_CD' field that are showing up with only 4 digits to include a leading zero.  The function is below.  When I step through the function it works as expected.  When I use it in a query, I step through it and it seems to output what I am looking for (the leading zeroes where appropriate).  However when I run the query, and it asks me if I want to update all of the row(s).  Then I look at the table, each ZIP_CD value in each record is blank.  I have no idea why it is doing this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```vb
Option Compare Database

Function EditLeadingZeroes(ZipCode As String)
    If Len(ZipCode) < 5 Then
        ZipCode = Format(ZipCode, "00000")
    Else
        ZipCode = ZipCode
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Is your ZIP_CD field numeric?

Comment: No its a text field

Comment: It might help to see the query that is prompting the update then. Are you *intending to* update all of the records with the properly formatted string?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Add `EditLeadingZeroes = ZipCode` at the end.

Comment: Beautiful Ahmed!  It's been so long since I've worked on this stuff that I've forgotten the basic stuff.  Thank you very much!